# QML Tumbler with sprite or SpriteSequence

Tags: qt, qml

I use to call following function jumpTo() to change a sprite in sprite sequence, but it use to change the sprite abruptly.

Is it possible to animate when i call function ... digit.jumpTo(n); ... to animate sprites to scroll up  ?

Or Can i use sprite's with a tumbler ?

```
import QtQuick 2.0

Item {

    id: numberImageSprite
    //anchors.centerIn: parent
    width: 20
    height: 20

    SpriteSequence {
            id: digit
            width: 12
            height: 16
            interpolate: false
            goalSprite: ""
            running: true
            property var sourceImage: 'files/abc.png'
            Sprite{
                name: "0"
                source: digit.sourceImage
                frameCount: 1
                frameWidth: 10
                frameHeight: 16
                frameX: 0
                frameY: 0
            }
            Sprite{
                name: "1"
                source: digit.sourceImage
                frameCount: 1
                frameWidth: 9
                frameHeight: 16
                frameX: 12
                frameY: 0
            }

    }

    function setNumber(n){
       digit.jumpTo(n);
    }


}
```

Comment: Did you read this article - [Sprite Animations with SpriteSequence](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtquick-imageelements-example.html#sprite-animations-with-spritesequence)?

Comment: so do i have to add following property to my sprite "frameDuration" & "to"... ?

Comment: please suggest if we can use tumbler for this task .. to have sprites with tumbler .. ?

Comment: you have to clarify the question. it's unclear now what you want to archive.

Comment: Means how to Animate sprites to scroll upward ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can forget about Sprites when you want to use [Tumbler](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtquick-controls2-tumbler.html). You can use the Image in your delegate. Here is a working example. I added -/+ buttons for you to see how manually you can rotate the [Tumbler](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtquick-controls2-tumbler.html).

```
 Item{
        id: itm
        anchors.fill: parent
        Row{
            Button{
                width: 36
                text: '-'
                onClicked: digitsTumbler.currentIndex = digitsTumbler.currentIndex == 0 ? digitsTumbler.count-1 : digitsTumbler.currentIndex-1;
            }

            Tumbler {
                id: digitsTumbler
                model: 10
                visibleItemCount: 1
                height: 36
                width: 36
                delegate: Item{
                    width: 36
                    height: 36
                    clip: true
                    Image{
                        x:0
                        y:0
                        sourceSize: Qt.size(360,36)
                        source: "qrc:///d.png"
                        transform: Translate{x: index*-36 ; y:0}
                    }
                }
            }
            Button{
                width: 36
                text: '+'
                onClicked: digitsTumbler.currentIndex = digitsTumbler.currentIndex == digitsTumbler.count-1 ? 0 : digitsTumbler.currentIndex+1;
            }
        }
    }
```

`d.png` is attached as a sample image containing digits from 0 to 9.

[image]

Comment: Thanks I will try this.. what if image number are not at same distance from each other as in your case each number is at distance of x = 36 .. from each other.. then what to do ..?

Comment: You can then use an array to hold those distances and reference them using the index like ```var offsets = [ [0,0] , [37,1] , [72,0] , ....]``` and ```Translate{x: offset[index][0] *-1 ; y:offset[index][1] * -1}```

Comment: its working fine.. but one issue left... when first times my GUI start i want to show .. number 8 or any other number 5,6,7.... but when i set.... digitsTumbler.currentIndex = 8 .... it shows me transition form 0 to 8 .... i do not want to see that transition first time.. i directly want to see that number ... please suggest how to do this task

Comment: @Katoch, you then can call ```positionViewAtIndex(9, Tumbler.Center)``` which will move the Tumbler without animating it.

Comment: yes it did the trick .. positionViewAtIndex .. some how i did this before seeing your reply... thanks .. :-)